# Matching vim characters with regex to highlight {}

Tags: vim

What can I add to my vim config so that my brackets {} become bold?

```
:match myGroup {|}
```

I want something like this, the | is like the regex OR operator. Also, is there a reference I can use to figure out how to match correctly? How does it differ from normal regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want something like this

I suppose

```
:hi myGroup term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
:match myGroup /{\|}/
```

> How does it differ from normal regex?

This is Vim regex. Find more about it with Vim's embedded help, like `:h regexp`, `:h syn-pattern` and so on.

> What can I add to my vim config

Try, for example, this

```
augroup vimrc | au!
    autocmd ColorScheme * hi Brace term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
    autocmd Syntax * syn match Brace /{\|}/
augroup end
```